# A stable version that meets FCC requirement

Tags: cobalt

We are wondering how to meet FCC's requirement.

Would Cobalt provide a stable version to meet FCC requirement?

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cobalt team is actively working on WAI-ARIA support and will open-source it as soon as it is ready. At the moment we cannot provide a specific date but we acknowledge the importance of FCC compliance.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!